# Linear Algebra: Proof Question Concerning Uniqueness of RREF and Use of Fields

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-fields

I am trying to figure out why the Reduced Row Echelon Form of a matrix is unique  with this [proof](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Yuster19807.pdf) I found on the internet but one particular part of this proof is confusing me ([here](https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/the-reduced-row-echelon-form-of-a-matrix-is-unique-a-simple-proof) is the website). Now, this proof looks fine in my opinion, except I would notate $(B_{jn}-C_{jn})u_n=0$ as $u_n(B_{jn}-C_{jn})=0$, so that way $u_n\in \mathbb{F}$ and on the left hand side (I could be wrong though). Now, suppose $u_n\neq 0$. Thus, multiplying on the left by $u_n^{-1}$ yields $B_{jn}-C_{jn}=u_n^{-1}0$. However, how do we know that $u_n^{-1}0=0$ to deduce that $B_{jn}=C_{jn}$ which is the contradiction I want.

Comment: I do not know why the answer was deleted by the user who posted it, but it made sense. The answer was appreciated.

Comment: I'll have it back up in a second, I misread what $u_n$ was.

Comment: I get the idea though which you thought of. If you upload this, I will give the answer to you. Your work not mine: let $u^{-1}0=u^{-1}(0+0)=u^{-1}0+u^{-1}0$. By canceling, $u^{-1}0-u^{-1}0=u^{-1}0=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you essentially want to show that scalar multiplication by the zero matrix yields the zero matrix.

Note that $n \times m$ matrices form an additive group, and the matrix $0_{n \times m}$, the matrix consisting of all zeros, is the identity of that group. Thus $0_{n \times m} = 0_{n \times m} + 0_{n \times m}$. Furthermore, scalar multiplication distributes over matrix addition, which allows us to say that for any scalar $a \in F$,

$a0_{n \times m} = a(0_{n \times m} + 0_{n \times m}) = a0_{n \times m} + a0_{n \times m}$.

Now by the cancellation property of groups, we may say that $0_{n \times m} = a0_{n \times m}$.

Alternatively, one can see that this follows by first proving the analog for rings, and then using the definition of scalar multiplication for matrices.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't find that proof particularly simple. The key fact for the RREF $U$ of the matrix $A$ is that there exists an invertible matrix $F$ such that $U=FA$.

The second key fact is that a column of $U$ is a linear combination of other columns of $U$ if and only if the corresponding column of $A$ is the linear combination of the corresponding columns of $A$ *with the same coefficients*. More precisely, if $\{i_0,i_1,\dots,i_r\}$ are distinct column indices, then
$$
u_{i_0}=c_1u_{i_1}+\dots+c_ku_{i_r}
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
a_{i_0}=c_1a_{i_1}+\dots+c_ka_{i_r}
$$
(where $u_i$ are the columns of $U$ and $a_i$ the columns of $A$). This is an easy consequence of how matrix multiplication is performed.

Now the pivot columns in $U$ are the first $k$ columns of the identity matrix (where $k$ is the rank of $A$), so the nonpivot columns in $U$ just tell how this column is obtained as a linear combination of the pivot columns at its left. This only depends on the linear relations between the columns of $A$. The pivot columns are uniquely determined, because a column is pivot if and only if it is not a linear combination of the ones at its left.

Just to make an example, if $U$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & -3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then we have, for the columns of $A$,
$$
\begin{cases}
a_2=2a_1 \\
a_4=-3a_1+2a_3 \\
a_5=a_1 \\
a_7=2a_1+3a_3+4a_6
\end{cases}
$$
because of the corresponding relations between the columns of $U$.